# How do I install the Ubuntu One control panel?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, ubuntu-one, ppa

Is it possible to install the new Ubuntu One control panel in Ubuntu versions 10.04 or 10.10? I referred [this](http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2011/06/natty-ubuntuone-control-panel-in.html) page, but it suggests of installing Nightly builds, while I'll prefer to have stable builds.

Comment: The Nightly PPA is based on the stable builds. You can use it worryless.

Answer (score 2):

We don't currently build up to date stable version packages for 10.04 or 10.10.  If you want a later version, you'll either have to upgrade to a newer Ubuntu release, or use our nightly releases PPA (which may lead to occasional breakage that you wouldn't see using the versions from the main Ubuntu archives).